# Laravel4 scoping on related models, and weirdness thereof

Tags: php, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

I have an `Activity` model which refers to a `Type` model.

Then I have a `Schedule` model that may refer to an `Activity`.

So I might want to query schedules based on activity *type* (which could be NULL, but that's irrelevant; I just need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`...).

Laravel4's Eloquent allows me to write a *scoper* (here I want a *negative* scoper) and write

```
Schedule::where(...)->notOfType(myType)->...
```

Trying to go with [eager loading constraints](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) turned out to be too awkward

```
Schedule::with(array('activities' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('activity_description', 'like', '%lots of lulz%');
}))->get();
```

...because here I'm not querying on an attribute of `Activity`, the directly related model of `Schedule`, but on an attribute of `Type`. I tried several versions of nested `with`s before turning to good ol' JOINs.

```
public function scopeNotOfType($query, $type) {
    $query  
    ->leftJoin('activities',     'schedule.activity_id', '=', 'activities.id')
    ->leftJoin('activity_types', 'activities.type_id',   '=', 'activity_types.id')
    ->where('activity_types.name', '!=', $type->name);
}
```

meaning to join activities to schedules based on activity_id, and *then* join the types to the activities based on type_id. At that point my selection condition would run on the name field of the type.

No errors, and for very very simple data it even worked, but then on closer inspection it turned out that the data were all wrong. The query executed and a simple (too simple!) check with a SQL analyzer found the expected data being returned, *only to disappear from the Eloquent model*.

The first hint - well, more of a kick in the teeth - about what was going on was that my seeded `Schedule`, once retrieved by the filter, seemed to have a description field of "**Type**(1)Description" instead of the expected "**Schedule**(1)Description".

Whenever a field existed with the same name in more than one Model, I was getting the value from the wrong model instead than from `Schedule`. *Aha*. The fact is that Laravel4 is PHP and retrieves SQL fields as array *in order*, and since the `SELECT` generated by the above `JOIN`s was something like,

```
+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| schedule_id    | description | type_id | description |
+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
| 1              | Sched_Desc  | 1       | Type_Desc   |
| 2              | Sched2_Desc | 7       | Type7_Desc  |
+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

...when the PDO driver retrieved the field values, the *last* instance of `description`, the description of the *type*, above in the fourth column, **overwrote** the description of the schedule in the second.

Comment: Please post the answer/solution, for future reference (I didn't read it tho).

Comment: Sorry, I had absent-mindedly written it in the *question*. Now I've done it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution I

The obvious solution was to only select those fields I needed. Since here I was scoping `Schedule` and I couldn't care less for the related models, I just specified `Schedule` fields with `select()`:

```
public function scopeNotOfType($query, $type) {
$query 
    ->leftJoin('activities',     'schedule.activity_id', '=', 'activities.id')
    ->leftJoin('activity_types', 'activities.type_id',   '=', 'activity_types.id')
    ->select('schedule.*')
->where('activity_types.name', '!=', $type->name);
}
```

...and behold, only the `Schedule` fields are retrieved, no more field name conflicts.

## Solution II

Another solution would be to encode the table name in the field itself, i.e., have a field named `activity.activity_description`, so that `activity_description` no longer clashes with `<something-else>_description`; but that feels even more awkward, and may not be always convenient.

Comment: +1, for the hard work to figure it out and posting the answer for the community.